# join oracle database table with table of custom type

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, inner-join, user-defined-types

I want to join a table say EMPLOYEE with another custom oracle type MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST.
MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST is a table of a custom oracle type CRITERIA. All DDL as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
type CRITERIA as object (
DOB DATETIME,
SALARY NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE
MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST IS TABLE OF CRITERIA;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE{
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(20 BYTE),
    DOB DATETIME,
    SALARY NUMBER
}
```

What I am actually trying to achieve is,

```
var allEmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
var filteredList = new List<Employee>();
var matchingCriteria = new List<MatchingCritera>{
    new MatchingCritera(){DOB = <date1>, salary = <sal1>},
    new MatchingCritera(){DOB = <date2>, salary = <sal2>},
    new MatchingCritera(){DOB = <date3>, salary = <sal1>}
}
foreach(var emp in allEmployeeList)
{
    foreach(var criteria in matchingCriteria)
    {
        if(emp.DOB == criteria.DOB && emp.salary = criteria.salary)
        {
            filteredList.Add(emp);
        }
    }
}
```

I want this same logic to be in SP. I am currently doing as follows which is working fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
type IDTYPE as object (
id NUMBER
);
CREATE OR REPLACE
type IDTABLETYPE IS TABLE OF IDTYPE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_FILTERED_EMPLOYEE (
   IN_CRITERIA_LIST   IN       MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST,
   CUR_OUT            OUT      sys_refcursor
)
IS

V_ID_TABLE IDTABLETYPE;
V_TEMP_ID_COLL EMPLOYEE_ID;

BEGIN

   V_ID_TABLE := IDTABLETYPE();
   V_TEMP_ID_COLL := EMPLOYEE_ID();

   IF IN_CRITERIA_LIST.COUNT > 0 THEN
     FOR i IN IN_CRITERIA_LIST.FIRST .. IN_CRITERIA_LIST.LAST
     LOOP
        SELECT EMP.ID BULK COLLECT INTO V_TEMP_ID_COLL FROM EMPLOYEE EMP WHERE
        EMP.DOB = IN_CRITERIA_LIST(i).DOB
        AND EMP.SALARY = IN_CRITERIA_LIST(i).SALARY
        ORDER BY EMP.ID DESC;

        IF (V_TEMP_ID_COLL.COUNT > 0) THEN
         FOR j IN V_TEMP_ID_COLL.FIRST .. V_TEMP_ID_COLL.LAST
          LOOP
            V_ID_TABLE.extend();
            V_ID_TABLE(V_ID_TABLE.count) := IDTYPE(TO_NUMBER(V_TEMP_ID_COLL(j)));
          END LOOP;
        END IF;
     END LOOP;
   END IF;

   OPEN CUR_OUT FOR
   SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE EMP WHERE EMP.ID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(V_ID_TABLE));
END;
```

I want to remove the for loop on IN_CRITERIA_LIST, as it is impacting the performance, and do something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
INNER JOIN MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST MCL ON 
EMP.DOB = MCL.DOB
AND EMP.SALARY = MCL.SALARY
ORDER BY TD.TRANS_DASHBOARD_ID DESC;
```

Can someone guide how I can join my custom table of UDT with and oracle table?

Comment: I can not create a temporary table and put all matching_criteria_list into it, as we will be calling the SP from a multithreaded application.

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type - it has `DATE` (years to seconds) or `TIMESTAMP` (years to fractional seconds plus optional time zone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
INNER JOIN TABLE(IN_CRITERIA_LIST) MCL ON 
EMP.DOB = MCL.DOB
AND EMP.SALARY = MCL.SALARY
ORDER BY TD.TRANS_DASHBOARD_ID DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need an `IDTYPE` object or all the PL/SQL loops (or even joins):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_FILTERED_EMPLOYEE (
   IN_CRITERIA_LIST   IN       MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST,
   CUR_OUT            OUT      sys_refcursor
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN CUR_OUT FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM   EMPLOYEE
    WHERE  CRITERIA( dob, salary ) MEMBER OF IN_CRITERIA_LIST;
END;
/
```

Comment: How will CRITERIA( dob, salary ) above will get mapped to the respective columns of EMPLOYEE table? Does it imply writing a join as in my answer above?

Comment: @shrutisingh There is no join, just a filter against the collection passed in as a bind parameter.

Comment: @shrutisingh You can look at the explain plan for `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE CRITERIA( dob, salary ) MEMBER OF MATCHING_CRITERIA_LIST( CRITERIA( DATE '1970-01-01', 20000 ) )` and see that there is no join.